# What game is this music featured in Garry's Mod Idiot Box from?

Tags: game-identification

I was watching some funny Garry's Mod Idiot Box episodes on YouTube.  In [episode 3 at 5:41](https://youtu.be/Q4DxWpnmmMk?t=5m41s) is a scene that has some music being played in the background.  What game is from? It sounds so familiar to me, but I can't put a name to it.  It vaguely reminds of an old N64 game.

The video below starts at 5:41, right where the music is heard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the video's description there's a link:

> Visit the blog for the music list and FAQ! [http://dasboschitt.blogspot.com/2009/...](http://dasboschitt.blogspot.com/2009/03/music-used.html)

According to that, it's a section from the track “Water Caverns” from the Nintendo 64 classic *Goldeneye 007*. Independent YouTube research confirms this: